# Почему indexOf() возвращает одинаковое значение для двух разных пустых строк?

Tags: java, строки

Почему этот код выводит `Index = 0` для `b` и `s`?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Arr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        String s = new String();
        myList.add(s);
        String b = new String();
        myList.add(b);

        int idx = myList.indexOf(b);
        System.out.println("Index b=" + idx);
        int idx2 = myList.indexOf(s);
        System.out.println("Index s=" + idx2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

В методе `ArrayList.indexOf()` сравнение  объектов реализовано следующим образом

```
int indexOf(Object o) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
    if (o == null) {
      if (get(i) == null)
        return i;
    } else {
      if (o.equals(get(i)))
        return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Т.к переменные `a` и `b` представляют собой пустые строки, то

```
a.equals(b) == true
```

Т.е., с точки зрения списка, в списке находятся два идентичных объекта. А значит метод `indexOf` возвращает индекс первого из них

Comment: Только методу `indexOf` плевать на то, один это объект или два разных (кстати, тут два разных) - там сравнение через `equals` реализовано...

Comment: Объекты все же будут разные.

Comment: @AlexChermenin @Nofate♦ Штирлиц еще никогда не был так близко к провалу. Спасибо за пинок. Ответ переписал